# Users receiving multiple notifications (timeline cards) on Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I have an app that sends out notifications to users (timeline cards) and some of the users are reporting that they are receiving the same timeline card multiple times (up to 5 times in one instance).  Has anyone encountered this?  My app is utilizing the Mirror API.

I've reviewed my log files and only see the timeline card produced once.  I'm at a loss.  I'll provide any code or logs that are needed.  My app is written in Python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be happening. If you're seeing it persist, file a bug in the official issue tracker.

If you do file a bug, there's one thing that might help Google find the root cause. Do a [timeline.list](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/list#examples) on a user who reports the multiple notifications. Does the API show multiple cards? If so, include the JSON representation of them (including the ID)

The specific code to do this list depends on the language you're developing in. Here's an example of how to do it in Java:

```
  public static List<TimelineItem> retrieveAllTimelineItems(Mirror service) {
    List<TimelineItem> result = new ArrayList<TimelineItem>();
    try {
      Timeline.List request = service.timeline().list();
      do {
        TimelineListResponse timelineItems = request.execute();
        if (timelineItems.getItems() != null && timelineItems.getItems().length() > 0) {
          result.addAll(timelineItems.getItems());
          request.setPageToken(timelineItems.getNextPageToken());
        } else {
          break;
        }
      } while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("An error occurred: " + e);
      return null;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Jenny.  How do I do a timeline.list?

Comment: I see how to do the timeline.list now.